# How can I stop Microsoft Dynamics NAV instance to start automatically after server restart

Tags: nav

When my server restart, I would like that my NAV instance does not restart automatically

Do you know where do I have to do the setup for this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found how to do that.
You just have to go to the instance properties in the list of the windows services, and there you have an option to say if you want to restart the instance automatically or manually